# Problem with warped jack stud while converting from door frame to drywalled rough opening

Tags: drywall

I am working on converting what used to be a swing closet door to drywalled opening and later putting on a bi-fold door. When I removed the door frame and casing I noticed that one of the jack studs is warped so if I just put the drywall on it, it will be uneven as well.

Would you guys recommend trying to replace the jack stud and what if the stud that the jack stud is attached to is uneven as well ?  Or is there a way to put the drywall i a way that it ignores the slope in the stud - the difference between the two farthest points is roughly 3/8 inch?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the jack stud/trimmer isn't terribly difficult. I've done it many times when lengthening headers to increase opening widths. That might be the simplest fix if the king isn't also warped.

- Cut the nails penetrating each end with a reciprocating saw - don't cut deeper than 1-1/2" so trim covers the cuts in the drywall
- Remove any nails in the face of the stud
- Find and remove drywall screws penetrating the stud
- Run a pair of longer screws into the stud near one end, leaving them 3/4" proud
- Pry the stud out with a bar or large hammer on the screw heads

Otherwise, run some 3" screws in to tighten and straighten the jack as much as it'll go, then rely on your corner bead, which can easily take care of a 1/2" twist (1/4" at each end), for example:

- Install your drywall as normal
- Set the innermost (opposite) ends of both corner beads
- Use a framing square to set the opposite ends square with the previous set opposing ends
- Check the bead on the wall face with the square to be sure the bead is slightly proud of the drywall plane. It's easy to pull it in too far, essentially creating a curve in the wall.

Be aware that the second approach might reduce your finished opening width that 1/4".

Answer (score 0):

Either plane down the high points, or shim the low points. Or a bit of both.

Or go old-school and plaster it rather than using drywall.

I suppose a "new school" fix would be great globs of construction adhesive and remembering not to crank on the screws over the low points. Not one I'm all that fond of .vs. using solid shims, though.